# YouTube properties pass but not reflected in the video

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am using YouTube V3 Player API.

```
var player;

    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '315',
        width: '560',
        videoId: id,
        host: 'https://www.youtube.com',
        playerVars: {
            'autoplay': 1,
            'controls': 1,
            'disablekb': 1,
            'enablejsapi': 1,
            'iv_load_policy': 3,
            'loop': 1,
            'modestbranding': 1,
            'showinfo': 0,

        },
        events: {

        }
    });
```

The problem is that the properties that I've setup don't work. I see them in the query string that are passed in the embed URL, but autoplay doesn't start, modestbranding doesn't work, etc. The player does appear in the page though with the video corresponding to the id.

Testing it in localhost.

Comment: Which browser are you testing in?

Comment: @SteveMulvihill Chrome latest version on Windows

Comment: Can you test in another browser like FF and let me know if autoplay works?

Comment: @SteveMulvihill tested, it works in Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has reciently updated their Autoplay policies, videos must be muted to allow for autoplay in Chrome:

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

To mute video try the following:

```
var player;

    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '315',
        width: '560',
        videoId: id,
        host: 'https://www.youtube.com',
        playerVars: {
            'autoplay': 1,
            'controls': 1,
            'disablekb': 1,
            'enablejsapi': 1,
            'iv_load_policy': 3,
            'loop': 1,
            'modestbranding': 1,
            'showinfo': 0,

        },
        events: {
          onReady: function(e) {
            e.target.mute();
          }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I use mute=1, and it still not auto playing.

Comment: Updated my answer